# VBA - define range with column and row index - error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, methods, range

During the test of the code below, I was referring to  a range as Saved.Range("C3:C66") and everything was working.
Now I have to switch to cell index(Saved.Range(Cells(3, colIndex), Cells(66, colIndex))), as the column index is variable, but something is not working. Even if I use the indexes for the cells an error (runtime error 1004 vba method range of object _worksheet failed) appears.
Any help is highly appreciated in advance.

```
   Sub WriteToWorksheetFromBackup(dict As Dictionary, sh As Worksheet)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim IDnumber As Variant, objectID As clsDetector
    Dim row As Long
    row = 7
    
' Check keys in sheet Saved, against the dictionary and write on a sheet

    'For Each cell In Saved.Range("C3:C66")
    
    For Each cell In Saved.Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(66, 3))
    
        IDnumber = cell.Value
        If dict.Exists(IDnumber) Then
            Set objectID = dict(IDnumber)
            With objectID
                sh.Cells(row, 1).Value = IDnumber
                sh.Cells(row, 2).Value = .DetectorType
                sh.Cells(row, 3).Value = .DetectorZone
                sh.Cells(row, 4).Value = .DetectorNo
                sh.Cells(row, 5).Value = .DetectorDeck
                sh.Cells(row, 6).Value = .DetectorLocation
                sh.Cells(row, 7).Value = .DetectorTestCount
                sh.Cells(row, 8).Value = .DetectorArea
                row = row + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify the `cells`, they are referring to a different sheet than Saved. So `Saved.Range(Saved.Cells(3, 3), Saved.Cells(66, 3))`

Comment: Thank you very much. The answer can not be more clear.